# Perform an action on microphone input

Tags: c#, microphone, voice-recognition

I am writing a program that involves voice recognition. I want it to run in the taskbar then when some one speaks into the mic for it to wake up and then perform an action. How would I go about making wake up when someone speaks without a loop checking for a change in input volume?

Answer (score 2):

In the end, a microphone records a sound data from a continuous virtual stream. If you compare this to a keyboard, there is a defined moment when a key is pressed - an event. There is no such moment or event in sound - someone has to decide when the volume is high enough to act on it.

So something will have to analyse the data in order to act on it. And unless I'm wrong and a sound card has such functionality, you'll have to do it yourself.

Perhaps you don't have to analyse all data - a peek every 100ms might suffice?